# Embedded PowerApps on SharePoint page doesn't work properly in IE 11

Tags: internet-explorer, embed, sharepoint-online, powerapps

I embedded a PowerApps application on a SharePoint page using the PowerApps (preview) webpart and also the Embed webpart (iframe).

I tried to open the page in IE 11, but the app is not loaded properly, instead, I get the Sign in screen. After a few page refreshes, the app is loaded properly.

This is happening on both webparts, IE compatibility view is switched off. Also, the embedded app is from the same tenant.

This works fine in Chrome and Mozilla.

Has anyone seen this behavior before or is this a known issue?

Answer (score 0):

It can be possible that due to cache and cookies, app did not load properly and asked you for sign in.

I suggest you to clear the cache and cookies for that specific SharePoint site and sign in again may help to fix this issue for IE 11 browser.

I tested the issue with IE 11 browser and try to add power app as an embedded iframe and as an embedded power app in SharePoint site.

It asked for sign in for first time and then it loaded every time without any issue.

[image]